# Will object instances occur some memory leaks?

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I found a utility class that used for jdbc operations.

```
public ResultSet executePreparedStatementQuery(String sql, ArrayList args)
        throws ValidationException {

    try {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds = getDataSource(ctx);
        conn = ds.getConnection();
        CustomLogger.getLogger("JDBCUtility").logConnection(conn, true, 3);
        pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        int count = 1;
        Iterator iter = args.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Object obj = iter.next();
            setPreparedStatementField(count, obj);
            count++;
        }
        rs = pStmt.executeQuery();

    } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
        close();
        throw new ValidationException(sqlEx.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception cnfe) {
        close();
        cnfe.printStackTrace();
        throw new ValidationException(cnfe.getMessage());
    }

    return rs;
}
```

all the connection,statement and resultset are refered by non static class variables.will This occur to leak memory when calling  `rs = dbutil.executePreparedStatementQuery(strQuery, values);` after creating some JDBCUtility instances(dbutil) inside anather class?

thanks in advance..!

Comment: why do you think so ?

Comment: because every instance holds connection and resultset objects

Comment: close() for close all connection, statements and resultsets